# Javascript/Jquery Using Regex (or not) to add <span> to vowels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

New to coding and need some help.

Currently my code output numbers from 1-99, it then display some text next to the number depending on the conditions. E.g numbers that are divisible by 3 has 'Java', divisible by 5 has 'Script' and if they are both the it display 'JavaScript'.

My goal now is when a user click on a vowel, it will pop up a number correspondent with the vowel. E.g a = 0, e = 1, i = 2, o = 3 and u = 4. So on the page when some click on any letter a it will have a pop up displaying 0 etc etc.

I've managed to use regex (I believe) to source out the letter a and replace it with 44 to see if it was working. From my research the best solution is putting these vowels into a span and then put a mouseclick on it. I'm not sure how I would do this, how do I find the vowels and put a a/e/i/o/u around it?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

(function() {

    function getContent(i, str, match, replaceFn) {
        //find the vowels and wrap them in a span
        //span will have ID or class that we can attach a click handler to.
        var straeiou = "<p>" + i + " <span class='foo'>" + str + "</span></p>";
        var vowela = /a/gi;
        var newvowela = straeiou.replace(vowela, "44");

        document.write(newvowela);

    }

    function num() {
        for (var i=1; i<100; i++) {

            if (i%3==0 && i%5==0) {
                $('#demo').append(getContent(i, "JavaScript"));
            }
            else if (i%3==0) {
                $('#demo').append(getContent(i, "Java"));
            }
            else if (i%5==0) {
                $('#demo').append(getContent(i, "Script"));
            } 
            else {
                $('#demo').append(getContent(i, ""));
            }
        }
    }
    num();

    // $('aeiou').click(function() {
        // alert('clicked');
    // });
}());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a span around the vowels using the following code:

```
$("#demo").html(
    $("#demo").html().replace(/(a|e|i|o|u)/ig, "<span>$1</span>")
);
```

Then you can add a click event to all the `span` elements in `#demo` and check the content to know the value for the letters. I would put the letters and numbers in an object so you can retrieve them easily like so:

```
var a = {
    a: 0,
    e: 1,
    i: 2,
    o: 3,
    u: 4
};

alert(a["a"]);
// Will display 0
```

Comment: You should use `.text()` instead of `.html()` (you don't want `&amp;` to be turned into `&<span>a</span>mp;` for instance)

Comment: Using `.text()` like that won't work either, because you won't actually be creating `span` elements, but displaying literally "<span>a</span>".

Comment: I have tested the code several times with `.html()` and it worked just fine.

Comment: "<span>$1</span>") what does $1 mean?

Comment: the `$1` will be replaced by the code between `(` and `)` in the previous parameter. In this example, this is any vowel.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you code if very chaotic and is currently broken.

You are using jQuery's `.append()` method to append the result returned by you function  `getContent()`, however currently `getContent()` doesn't return anything.

Instead you use `document.write` which overwrites the whole content of the page. As an beginner you should forget that `document.write` exists. It's an antiquated method that has many pitfalls.

Then your attempt to replace the letter `a` also replaces everything inside your HTML, so that it currently produces something like

```
<p>3 <sp44n cl44ss='foo'>J44v44</sp44n></p>
```

Finally (in a minor point) your function has two unused parameters (`match` and `replaceFn`).

To solve your problem, the first question has to be: Why do you want to (or have to) use regular expression? In thsi simple case it seems easier to just add the `span`s to string literals you have directly, e.g.:

```
$('#demo').append(getContent(i, "J<span>a</span>v<span>a</span>"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for assisting, you have solved the problem for me.

I have 2 more questions.

1. How would I make the code below shorter? I don't think this is an efficient way.

  $('.a').click(function() {
   alert('0');
  });
  
  $('.e').click(function() {
   alert('1');
  });
  
  $('.i').click(function() {
   alert('2');
  });
  
  $('.o').click(function() {
   alert('3');
  });
  
  $('.u').click(function() {
   alert('4');
  });

2. How can I improve on my Javascript? I really need to improve on this and fast. Books?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @vjnr If you have working code you can check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com . In any case you should post your follow-up questions with your improved code in a new question (either here or an codereview), because the comment section isn't really practical. Also be prepared to explain the background and purpose of you code (especially if it's homework or practice as it seems to be), because code optimization depends on what you want to achieve in the big picture.